# Team Task Management - End time with "error bar"

Tags: task-management, resource-management

A few months ago I was browsing Google for team task management software and came across a great looking concept that allowed tasks to be assigned to teams.  Within the team, resources could specify how much time they expected a given task to take and when the Gantt chart for the project showed those tasks, it would effectively have an error bar on the completion date spanning the resource with the least amount of expected time to the resource that expected to take the most.

For about a month now, I have been trying to track down what this tool was and have been unable to find it ever since.  Could anybody recommend the site that I am looking for that had this functionality?  I have included a mockup of how I remember it looking.  If the fastest team member worked on it, you could expect the task to be completed by the far left dot, and if the team member that thought they would take the longest worked on it, the task would stretch out to the far right date.
[image: Example of what the tool looked like]

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you take a look in one of these:

(some of them are cloud-free, others, cloud-payed, and there are also some you need to install in your server and administrate the tool yourself).

**If you don't want to see my whole analysis of Project Management Tools below, I will give you some good options to try:**

**OrangeScrum**:
https://www.orangescrum.com/

**Basecamp**:
https://basecamp.com/

**Redbooth:**
https://redbooth.com/

**Timeneye:**
https://www.timeneye.com/

**Float:**
https://www.float.com/

Monday:
https://monday.com/lang/pt/

**Teamdeck:**
https://teamdeck.io/

**If you prefer check all the Project Management Tools possible, see the reviews below (StackExchange didn't allow me to insert all the links).**

Good luck:

2plan: Opensource. Free, for desktop and selfhosted. No cloud version. I found it ugly, boring to use and incomplete.

Scheduleapp: Promised to be a task scheduling and workload app among collaborators for free. In fact, the already weak app gave bugs and didn't even work on my PC.

Kanbanchi: Expensive and bad.

Corepm: It promised to be the perfect application to work with 100% Prince2 methodology, but it turned out to be ugly, expensive and bad.

Asana: It's free up to 15 people. I am not a big fan. Just worth it in the free version and look there.

gpweb: Ugly, complicated, priceless, you have to ask for a quote.

GoodDay: Good for those who need to get a lot of people working on the project for free, as it's up to 25 users for free. Then $ 5 per user-month. Hence it is not worth it. Not that it's a bad app, but it's much better.

Aiveo: Cheap (1 CAD $ per user-month), and has a reasonable number of features. Simple yet clean and understandable interface. I didn't like much.

JIRA: Too simple! Many things are missing! It does not roll.

Kanbanflow: It didn't excite me.

Beebole: Not excited.

Time Cockpit: Ugly and expensive.

Good platforms but cost-effective doesn't pay:

Citrix Podio: I thought the value for money was bad.

Paymo: Beautiful interface, basic features. OK. The free version allows 1 user to use for free, but for full functionality the price goes up. Impracticable.

Liquidplanner: Very expensive and not even that good.

Wrike: In 2016, all the projects I was a manager of were made with wrike. The app is good, but the cost benefit is not worth it. At the time I had a team of 5 people. There are free or very cheap apps in this case. Free version of it is very

Mavenlink: $ 49 per user-month. It's a good app, but the value for money definitely doesn't pay off.

Runrun.it: Price $: 59.00 per user-month. Expensive for the amount of features it delivers.

Zoho PM: Too expensive for the little it offers.

RedBooth: 0 to 10 users, with feature limitations. 9 per user-month in the intermediate version. If you are looking for a free version, this may be a reasonable option.

Monday: It's beautiful, it has customizable fields, it's very easy to use, it has a lot of integrations (this is the + strong point), but the cost-effectiveness is bad.

Resourceguruapp: Similar to Teamdeck and float, but these two are better.

Nutcache: It's quite functional and not that expensive, but no matter what "look" you look at, there's always a better competitor than him.

Redmine: Open-source, and well-built in terms of software, Redmine gives rise to several "improved" versions of itself, but I found its interface itself too ugly and not functional.

Projectmanager: At a cost: $ 25 per user per month, the application is beautiful, functional but not competitive.

Harvest: Not excited.

ActionSpace: Bad value for money.

Best value for money:

Easyproject: For those who want a very complete application and are willing to pay a fair price for it.

Strength: Many features like document management, wiki, financial management, and product bug tracking

Weakness: Interface is not so easy to use, although not difficult.

Bitrix24: For whom: Looking for a complete intranet for your organization. One application for all company employees to do everything in (ERP).

Strength: So many features that you can not even list for low price.

Weakness: Interface loaded with so many features and not project oriented

Note: Despite having project functionality, Bitrix24 is and "sells" as a complete "desktop" for your company.

Basecamp: For those who need a workspace organizer and not a project management tool.

Strength: Price "ok" as there are infinite people and 500 GB of storage. The interface is so 'cute' that I describe it as 'a cuteness'. $ 99 per month for countless users and projects. The price, though not low, is stable (never rises as the company grows in size).

Weakness: It lacks many, many features.

Teamdeck: For Those Who Need Organizational Management and Scheduling and Workload Control

Strength: Their pricing form is very staggered, the app is beautiful, easy to use.

Weakness: Does not use agile methods, is not for managing projects.

Timecamp: Very similar to Teamdeck. But with some differences, I suggest that anyone who needs a scheduler and team workload control should try both and see which one is better. Essential difference: Timecamp has desktop app.

Samepage: For teams looking for a place to do the work, not to plan. For professional developers and project managers, it's not cool.

Strength: Excellent virtual collective desktop, very flexible. It is a place to "do" the work, not to plan it, and very cheap.

Weakness: Not much room to plan long-term work. It is a more "day to day" style planning.

Float: For those who need a good task scheduling and workload control tool and want to have cost flexibility every month.

Strength: The monthly price varies based on the number of people you assigned to the task in the month ($ 5 per user assigned to the task in the month), meaning you don't have to pay when you don't use it a lot.

Weakness: Lacks more advanced project management features

Freedcamp: For those who want to pay zero for a good tool, with numerous users and projects.

Strength: The zero cost version offers you a lot compared to the others.

Weakness: Honestly paid versions are not worth it.

My choice for personal use currently / my favorites:

RedmineUP: For those who want a complete and cost effective platform on the list.

Strength: Amount of functionality in a usable interface.

Weakness: It is built under Redmine, which has its usability limitations.

Timeneye: For those who want to store their own daily working hours at zero cost, and then analyze how you spend your working hours.

Strength: good interface, very high usability. Excellent working hours tracker

Weakness: Poor value for money on paid versions of the platform.

Orangescrum: For anyone who wants a cheap, responsive project management tool that delivers a lot of functionality

Strength: Very good price. $ 29.00 per month for up to 20 users.

Weak point: I would just say that there are competitors who 'deliver more' than him, but always charging more expensive.

Forecast.it: For those who want an excellent tool, with an 'infinite' number of users, but limited to two simultaneous 'open' projects.

Strength: I use the free 'quota' of 2 free projects quite satisfied.

Weakness: The task hierarchy is limited to two levels. The price for more than 2 projects goes up too much.

The one that is excellent but very expensive:

Easyredmine: Most complete application from this list. There is no functionality that exists in another application on this list that does not exist here either.

Cost: Initial plan for up to 25 people is $ 43 per month, but that's the "naked" price. A large part of the modules must be added and it is not cheap to do so....

Comment: You're posting a link to your website at the end of all your posts. Please note that is [considered spam](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Comment: Bruno, please focus on the particular feature that this question is about. Better list one solution and write why it fits the requirement, than list 20 solutions and not write about which fit the requirement.

Comment: Runrun.it is $10/user, not $59

Comment: @bruno, thanks for the long list.  It's actually interesting to see all of those tools in one place, but do you happen to know if any of them have the feature I described in my question?  That was the one thing in particular that I was trying to track back down.